# How to use web and api guards at the same time in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have build application with two parts: RESTful part for mobiles and web.

How can I use web/api guards at the same time? That I can register users with stadart web form, and accept request like as Restful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protect whatever routes are for your api with `auth:api` middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function(){
    //protected routes for API
});
```

We must make sure that your `users` table has an `api_token` column:

```
php artisan make:migration alter_users_table_add_api_token_column
```

Then inside of the `up` function:

```
Schema::table('users', function($table){
    $table->string('api_token', 60)->unique(); //this must be 60 characters
});
```

Finally in your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`, modify the create file to add your api_token

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'api_token' => str_random(60) //add this
    ]);
}
```

Now request to the `auth:api` protected routes will need to contain an `api_token` in their payload.

Comment: I dont have `AuthController` in Laravel 5.3

Comment: In your case how can I register user using `api_token`?

Comment: @Babaev I've modified my answer. You'll need to make these modiications in the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` under the `create()` function.

Comment: Okay, but how to register new user using RESTful interface?

Comment: @Babaev All users are given an api_token on creation. How they get created is up to you.

Comment: I dont understand you, my service is used by mobile clients, they should have registration from mobile device, sending RESTful reuest with user data

Comment: Ok. Send the request over https with a JSON payload to register. When they're created, they'll still get an `api_token` column. When sending further requests when they're logged in, make sure that the `api_token` from the `auth()->guard('api')->user()->api_token` is being used in the payload as the `api_token` parameter. Any routes you want to be resourceful, place them under the `Route::group` i showed you above, and simply do `Route::resource('model', 'controller');`

Comment: Could you share an example please, it is very important