# How to fix following error: InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [jwt] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I have followed following guide to make an Authentication Api, and an api which uses the authentication from the first one. I have done everything exactly the same, but i still get this error:

**InvalidArgumentException: Auth guard [jwt] is not defined. in file folder/to/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 84**

The guide i have followed is: https://medium.com/swlh/build-jwt-authentication-between-multiple-api-with-laravel-fbd03352aaa3

My `config/auth` looks like this:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        // 'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Then my `app/guard/JWTGuard.php` looks exactly like in the guide.
My `routes/api.php` look the following:

```
Route::middleware('auth:jwt')->resource('projects', ProjectController::class);
```

Does anybody has this issue before and know how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not famliar with this problem specifically in Laravel, but this is a common issue in all plataforms. For jwt CORS protection to work, it has to receive a JWT/CORS token, that is sent back in the next request. The normal solutions are: Or define an specific field in your page (the name is important, normally is _cors or something similar) OR deactivate CORS protection.

Comment: Is it cors? Really dont think this is related to cors errors

Comment: Cannot be sure, but the message make me to suspect this. You have several questions in SO about this, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477420/how-to-enable-both-api-and-web-guard-in-laravel

Comment: Ill look into it

Comment: If you find the exact solution, don't forget to answer your own question, for help future users!

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the guard you defined is named `api` not `jwt` ... `auth:api`

Comment: Okey thanks lagbox, but then laravel will whine about route login not defined.

Comment: because you are using the correct guard now but you are sending the wrong headers with your request

Comment: Which headers do you mean? I only send the Authorization header

Comment: you need to send headers to the application with the request to tell the application you are accepting JSON for the response

Comment: Iam doing that. I make my requests with Postman. I made an named route called login, which only returns "Unauthorized". So when my jwt token isnt correct, i will get redirected to that route. But now i always get there, even with a correct token. I am a newbie with laravel so not so much experience

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `routes/api.php`. The middleware shouldn't be "auth:jwt", but "auth:api". This did the trick for me.